# Multiplexer with variable size signals

Tags: arrays, matlab, simulink, multiplexing

I am using MATLAB/simulink 2014a and I would like to feed a multiplexer (with 3 ports) with 3 signals which have variable-sizes. But I get the error:

[image]

Someone could help me to solve the problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try the suggestions listed under "Examine the configurations..." etc?

Comment: As far as I know, Simulink DOES NOT support variable size data. It makes a lot of sense  actually. Tehrefore, youll need to just not use vatiable size.

Comment: Simulink supports variable size data. Mux does not support variable size data. If you just want to concatenate the data try using "Vector Concatenate" block.

Comment: @Navan is right, Simulink does support variable-size data, but not for all blocks. Unfortunately, the Mux block is not part of the list of blocks which support variable-size data, see [Simulink Block Support for Variable-Size Signals](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/simulink-block-support-for-variable-size-signals.html) in the documentation for more details. Use a Vector Concatenate block instead, as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all thanks for the comments. They helped. I try to write a comprehensive answer in this way if someone has my same question, he/she will find here a possible answer.

- MULTIPLEXER in SIMULINK don't support Variable-Size signals. You can give a look to which blocks of Simulink support variable-size signals here:
  http://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/simulink-block-support-for-variable-size-signals.html
  I think the reason is that the components of a mux signal must all have the same data type and cannot be hierarchical.
- To workaround this problem one way would be to use the block BUS CREATOR, the following:
  http://it.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/buscreator.html
- To be more clear you can give a look at the differences between MUX(demux) and bus creator here:
  http://fr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97787-what-is-the-difference-between-the-mux-demux-and-bus-creator-bus-selector-blocks-in-simulink

I hope this will help someone.